# What is phonestateintentreceiver.notifyPhoneCallState used for?

Tags: android, android-phone-call

Can anyone tell me what is the use of `phonestateintentreceiver.notifyPhoneCallState`?

Comment: This is called to receive a notification about an incoming phone call.

Answer (score 4):

I know it is too late to post an answer here, may be helpful for guys who refer this in future.

**notifyPhoneCallState has to be called if your application wishes to receive a notification about an incoming phone call.**

Comment: 1. it's deprecated and removed from SDK. 2. why only incoming? couldn't you use it for receiving outgoing phone call intents?

Answer (score 0):

Well... The first comment in the class says

> DO NOT USE THIS CLASS:      Use android.telephony.TelephonyManager and PhoneStateListener instead.

So maybe look into those other classes.

Comment: Thanks Jon7 for your answer but actually I want to just know the use of this particular class. I'll keep in mind your advice. Thanks