# PhoneSateIntentReceiver.NotifyPhoneCallState in android

Tags: android

Hello can anyone explain the use of **PhoneSateIntentReceiver.NotifyPhoneCallState in android**  and when this can be used...??

It would be great if you can give some example also.

thanks a lot.

Comment: Here is SO discussion on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6825794/what-is-phonestateintentreceiver-notifyphonecallstate-used-for

Comment: But there is no satisfactory answer there

Comment: First of, it seems it is depricated. Are you trying to use this or just for learning purpose? As far as I understand from the other link, it seems when you there is incoming call on this phone, this intent will be triggered.

Comment: yes this for just learning purpose ..... I confused in two ways : !) whether it triggers for incoming phone calls or when some call state changes... which will be more proper ....whats your view....????

Comment: There is no such class as `PhoneSateIntentReceiver`, let alone an inner class of it named `NotifyPhoneCallState`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

However , PhoneSateIntentReceiver.NotifyPhoneCallState is deprecated but earlier it was used to get notify for incoming phone calls .

Answer (score 0):

**for incoming phone calls .** 
 But don't use it ,just use **android.telephony.TelephonyManager** and **PhoneStateListener** instead.